# Creating Admin/User login system in PHP

Tags: php

I've done this sort of stuff this Python/Django a lot, but today I have to do this in PHP on an existing half-finished code. This is my first time with PHP.

Basically it's you usual login system, with admin login and user login.

My users table in my database contanins `sno, username, password, admin`, where `admin` is `1` for users with admin privileges.

Now while logging in, I understand I can simply check for the `admin` value for the whoever has logged in and `header("Location: adminhome.php");` if admin and `header("Location: userhome.php");` if not.

But how do I stop a regular user from accessing, say, `adminpage1.php` which is meant only for admins?

This is my first and only a one time job with PHP, otherwise I would go through various guid

Comment: If this is a one time job, why not go with an out of the box CMS, or even just a framework like CodeIgniter? It will save you the hassle of having to implement these core functionalities.

Comment: When you log the user in, are you setting anything in the `$_SESSION` var? If so, just put a check on the admin page for `if (isset($_SESSION['username']) === false){ header('Location: /') }` for example.

Answer (score 2):

After you verified that the user is an admin in the login.php, insert the follwoing

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["is_admin"] = true;
```

into login.php (or whaterver you called it, the file where the header() calls are,
and insert into adminhome.php the following

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["is_admin"]) && $_SESSION["is_admin"])
{
    echo "You are an admin!";
}
else
{
    header("Location: userhome.php");
}
```

That is secure and should work.

Comment: Okay so in every page where I want *only* admins to access, I'll have to put this code : 
`
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["is_admin"]) && $_SESSION["is_admin"])
{
    echo "You are an admin!";
}
else
{
    header("Location: userhome.php");
}

`

Comment: Yes exactly; useless sentence to get around character limit