# How should I creating admin and user

Tags: php

Am want to create admin and user page, but just by knowing the URL address they can navigate to any page.How can i restrict the page access?

```
<?php
include './connect.php';
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && (!empty($_POST['username'])) && (!empty($_POST['password']))) {
$postedUsername = $_POST['username'];
$postedPassword = $_POST['password'];
$userDatabaseFind = $database->login->findOne(array('username' => $postedUsername, 'password' => $postedPassword));
$storedUsername = $userDatabaseFind['username'];
$storedPassword = $userDatabaseFind['password'];

if (($postedUsername == $storedUsername) && ($postedPassword == $storedPassword)) {
    header('location:searchDetail.php');
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
}
?>
```

My Html code is

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        #page-wrapper{
            width: 400px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        input[type="text"] {
            width: 450px;
        }
        input[type="password"]{
            width: 450px;
        }
        body{
            background-image: url(images/image2.jpg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Signin Form</legend>
            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Username" name="username" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="button">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>
```

P.S-Please don't mention the password security

Modified Code:

```
<?php
include './connect.php';
session_start();
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && (!empty($_POST['username'])) && (!empty($_POST['password']))) {
$postedUsername = $_POST['username'];
$postedPassword = $_POST['password'];
$userDatabaseFind = $database->login->findOne(array('username' => $postedUsername, 'password' => $postedPassword));
$storedUsername = $userDatabaseFind['username'];
$storedPassword = $userDatabaseFind['password'];

if (($postedUsername == $storedUsername) && ($postedPassword == $storedPassword)) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $storedUsername;
    if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin'){
         header('location:searchDetail.php');
    }
    else{
        echo 'Hello world';
    }

} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: One possible solution would be to use a session variable to govern which level of user can access certain pages - when the user logs in assign the relevant information to the session variable. If they navigate to a page that is protected by the session variable checking mechanism and they meet the requirements they get access, otherwise they get redirected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Admin/User login system in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249973/creating-admin-user-login-system-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your database, I will presume you can differenciate between admin and a normal user. You can have a column with `user level`. Let say admin will have user level `1` and normal user will have user level `0`.

Now change this in your code.

```html
$storedUsername = $userDatabaseFind['username'];
$storedPassword = $userDatabaseFind['password'];
$storesuserlevel = $userDatabaseFind['userlevel'];

//Admin page

if (($postedUsername == $storedUsername) && ($postedPassword == $storedPassword) && $storesuserlevel == 1) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $postedUsername;
  $_SESSION['userlevel'] = '1';
    header('location:searchDetailadmin.php');// only accessed by the admin
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}

// Normal user

if (($postedUsername == $storedUsername) && ($postedPassword == $storedPassword) && $storesuserlevel >= 0) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $postedUsername;
  $_SESSION['userlevel'] = '0';
    header('location:searchDetail.php');// only accessed by both admin and user
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

To restrict a normal user from getting in the admin page use the below code in `searchDetailadmin.php`

```html
if($_SESSION['userlevel'] != 1 ){
header('location:searchDetail.php');
}
```

Hope this will help